# How to import package "constraints" in Go?

Tags: go, import

If you do the tour to learn go here :

https://go.dev/tour/

You may try to use constraints like Ordered.

However,

```
import "constraints"
```

returns an error :

```
package constraints is not in GOROOT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"constraints"` package is not part of the standard library and never was, except perhaps for early dev or beta releases before Go 1.18.

The correct import path is:

```
import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
```

As all code in `x/exp` it's outside of Go compatibility guarantee.

The reason for not including it in the standard library is mentioned here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50792